# Как мне правильно переиспользовать функционал?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Ребята, допустим, у меня есть два сайта. На первом сайте у меня есть страница с данными (первого сайта). Мне нужно как-то переиспользовать эту страницу на другом сайте. Через iframe? И да, первый и второй сайты - SPA. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Можно через iframe но если будут полосы прокрутки, будет сложно убрать.
Как вариант скопировать ctrl c ctrl v, и открыть доступ к API первого сайта для второго сайта.
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
вместо звездочки можно написать доменное имя
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin